# Unsupervised anomaly detection with factor analysis (in R)

Tags: r, classification, factor-analysis, outliers, unsupervised-learning

The basic idea i'm trying is to model the data with factor analysis, **assuming a latent variable structure** that underlies the observations. Labels for "real" anomalies are available and used for validation. Another important note is that the data does not have a "very" Gaussian nature.

Then, projecting the observations onto the new subspace found, and **looking for outliers** - i.e. finding the observations that digress from the underlying structure, assuming the anomalies i'm looking for will be more prevalent there.

Using R's *factanal*, with *varimax* (or *oblimin*) rotations, i have encountered the following result, which i'm not sure about :

- When projecting the **normalized** data (z-score) using the FA model found, classification/detection is poor ; but since factanal scales the data in advance, i believe this is the correct way(?)
- When projecting the **original** data (not normalized) using the same FA model, detection is much improved.

Could this be due to projecting the observations onto a subspace that assumes a low variance, much more "normal" distribution, thereby "aggravating" any anomalous points?

Would appreciate help/insight as to what i'm missing!

Thank you.

**Update:**
- LX yields much better classification than LX*, where L is the loadings matrix, X is the data matrix, and X* is the standardized data matrix. LX also yields better classification than in the following.
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-April/020278.html

Could the LX transformation be related to LDA?

Comment: It has nothing to do with normality. Simply factor analysis perfomed on standardized data (=correlations), centered data (=covariances), scaled data (=cosines) or raw data (=dot-products) often leaves quite different results. You shouldn't rely on default specification but think over what type of data narmalization will suit your task

Comment: Thanks. Could you possibly reference me to some sources describing those differences?

Comment: These needn't be described because the differences aren't systematic but depend on the data at hand, and the subject is obvious: supposing you're familiar with how FA works, then just use imagination.

Comment: Is there perhaps any relation to LDA?

Comment: FA is as such fairly distant from LDA. And LDA always works on centered or standardized data whereas FA/PCA sometimes (rarely) are performed on uncentered data.

Comment: Hello ttnphns, see update